# Guitar Amplifier issue

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

I'm new here and I need some help with an issue with my guitar amplifier. I connected my electric and electroacoustic guitars with it and both when connected, you can hear the sound of the connection on the amp if you turn up the volume on the guitars. But when playing the guitar, there's no signal output. When I try to move the cables, there's a screeching sound coming from the amp. Anyone had this issue and anyone's got a fix for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a different lead. Plugging in just a plug that's not connected to any wire can often make a sound on the amp.

Comment: Is the amp any of this equipment new, or have you had this setup all working previously?

Answer (score 1):

This happens with two different guitars, so it (probably) isn't the guitar.  Try a different lead, try a different amplifier.  Do whichever is more convenient first!   Probably the different lead. Unless your guitar-playing friend lives next door?

Answer (score 1):

The list of potential problems that may be causing your amplifier, cable, and guitar to not sound is quite long. It may be something as simple as dirt or corrosion in a connector, a defective guitar pickup, a defective solder connection on a circuit board, a guitar cable plug that is not securely plugged all the way in, and on and on. The usual procedure for finding the cause of these problems is a process of elimination, where each individual component is checked and cleared. Try your set-up with a different connecting cable that works fine on another amp, then try a different guitar, if that still doesn't work try your set-up with a different amp. If you still don't have any answers to your problems, this would be the time to load it up and take it to the repair shop and seek assistance from a professional technician. And I wish you good luck.